# Is there any way to resolve sonar scan error "Fail to get bootstrap index from server" occurred in github action?

Tags: sonarqube, github-actions, sonarqube-scan

For my angular library project, I am trying to run sonar scanner from GitHub actions.

I'm using my organization's SonarQube server (to host sonar report).
It works fine locally but throws this error when I try to perform a scan via GitHub actions:

[image: error]

**.yml file:**

```yaml
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Extract branch name
        shell: bash
        run: echo "##[set-output name=branch;]$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})"
        id: extract_branch

      - name: Bump Version and update the config with the new version
        run: |
          cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name: Install 
        run: |
          git rm -r package-lock.json
          npm cache clean --force
          npm install --force
      - name: Test 
        run: |
          npm run test

      - name: Run SONAR
        uses: sonarsource/sonarqube-scan-action@master
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}
```

**Sonar Properties:**

```
sonar.host.url= <host_url>
sonar.login= login 
sonar.password= password
sonar.projectKey= test-sonar
sonar.projectName= test-sonar
```